# Mongo docker with volume get error

Tags: mongodb, permissions, docker

After running `docker run --name mongo -p 27017:27017 -v ~/Documents/store/mongo/:/data/db -d mongo --smallfiles`

> [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open
>   lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod
>   instance already running?, terminating

In **store** directory, `ls -l`

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 MeoBeoI  staff  136 Dec  8 17:11 mongo
drwxr-xr-x  2 MeoBeoI  staff   68 Dec  9 10:20 redis
```

I use OSX 10.11.1

Comment: is there a mongod.lock file in /Documents/store/mongo/ ? If so delete it and run again

Comment: Thanks @Sharah Nair, but it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [mongo Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fcb9584617e63f1d3db8dc730fb8abb83653c7ad/3.2/Dockerfile):

- a [user mongodb is created](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fcb9584617e63f1d3db8dc730fb8abb83653c7ad/3.2/Dockerfile#L4)
- [/data/db is created and protected for mongodb:mongodb](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/fcb9584617e63f1d3db8dc730fb8abb83653c7ad/3.2/Dockerfile#L53)

So try and make sure to start your container with that user:

```
docker run --user mongodb ...
```

If that is not working, then fallback to the original docker run command (which runs as root by default) and define `run.sh` (that needs to be copied in your own image) which will:

- do the right `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db`
- call `entrypoint.sh mongod`

That is:

```
docker run ... run.sh
```

That would be an approach similar to [issue 7198 (Make uid & gid configurable for shared volumes)](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7198#issuecomment-158566258).